# Extend/Pad matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Say I have

```
A = [1 2 3]
    [4 5 6]
    [7 8 9]
```

I want to pad it with the first row and first column or last row and last column as many times as needed to create A nxn. For example, A 4x4 would be

```
 A = [1 1 2 3]
     [1 1 2 3]
     [4 4 5 6]
     [7 7 8 9]
```

and A 5x5 would be

```
 A = [1 1 2 3 3]
     [1 1 2 3 3]
     [4 4 5 6 6]
     [7 7 8 9 9]
     [7 7 8 9 9]
```

I'm aware that I could do `A.conservativeResize(4,4)` which gets me

```
 A = [1 2 3 0]
     [4 5 6 0]
     [7 8 9 0]
     [0 0 0 0]
```

then I could copy things around one by one, but is there a more efficient way to do this using Eigen?

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround using a nullary-expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Matrix3i A;
  A.reshaped() = VectorXi::LinSpaced(9,1,9);
  cout << A << "\n\n";
  int N = 5;
  MatrixXi B(N,N);
  B = MatrixXi::NullaryExpr(N, N, [&A,N] (Index i,Index j) {
        return A( std::max<Index>(0,i-(N-A.rows())),
                  std::max<Index>(0,j-(N-A.cols())) ); } );
  cout << B << "\n\n";
}
```

Another approach would be to create a clamped sequence of indices like `[0 0 0 1 2]`:

```
struct pad {
  Index size() const { return m_out_size; }
  Index operator[] (Index i) const { return std::max<Index>(0,i-(m_out_size-m_in_size)); }
  Index m_in_size, m_out_size;
};

B = A(pad{3,N}, pad{3,N});
```

This version requires the head of Eigen.

You can easily build on those examples to make them even more general and/or wrap them within functions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you elaborate on the `reshaped` part? I'm using Eigen 3.3.5 and it says "no member named `reshaped; did you mean Nested"? I also don't really get this part "This version requires the head of Eigen".

Comment: `reshaped` requires the head of Eigen, that is the devel branch from the repo. But I used `reshaped` only to initialize the matrix, you can also write `A.setRandom()` for testing!

Comment: BTW, I used your use case to demonstrate custom indexed generator in Eigen's doc: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html#title5

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, it's not true that `A.conservativeResize(4,4)` will get you a matrix with the added rows filled with zeros. The Eigen documentation says,

> In case values need to be appended to the matrix they will be uninitialized.

The new rows and columns will be filled with garbage, and seeing zeros is only a coincidence (unless you are compiling with a special preprocessor directive to Eigen). But this means that no unnecessary time is wasted writing zeros that you will overwrite anyway.

*Note: this code demonstrates how to get a matrix with your original matrix in the **top left corner***:

The best way to fill multiple values at once is to use Eigen's [block operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) and [`setConstant`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac2f1e50d1f567da38da1d2f07c5ab559). For example, if `A` is a matrix of size `old_size`x`old_size`:

```
A.conservativeResize(n, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Fill the end of each row and column
    A.row(i).tail(n - old_size).setConstant(A(i, old_size - 1));
    A.col(i).tail(n - old_size).setConstant(A(old_size - 1, i));
}
// Fill the bottom right block
A.bottomRightCorner(n - old_size, n - old_size).setConstant(A(old_size - 1, old_size - 1));
```

More importantly than being "efficient", these functions express your intent as a programmer.

*Edit: To get a padded matrix with your original matrix in the **middle:***

I just noticed your example pads around the original matrix in the middle, not in the top left. In this case, there is little point to using `conservativeResize()`, because the original values will only be copied to the top left corner. An outline of the solution is:

- Construct a new nxn matrix `B` of the desired size
- Copy your original matrix to the middle using

  `int start = (n - old_size + 1)/2;
  B.block(start, start, old_size, old_size) = A;`
- Fill in the outside values using block operations similar to my example above.